# How do I create random dots concentrated in a particular area in JS?

Tags: javascript, math, random, dotspatial

Need some conceptual help here. Currently, I have a random-dot function that creates two sets of dots (orange and blue) that spread out over a canvas. But I'm looking for a way to concentrate the dot density in random areas around the screen.

The code looks essentially like this:

```
var createBlueDots = function () {
       for (var i = 0; i <=someRandomNum; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        var rand_x = Math.random(i) * horz_max;
        var rand_y = Math.random(i) * vertical_max;
        context.arc(rand_x, rand_y, radius, 1, 2*Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle ="#0855A2";
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();   
        }
    }
createBlueDots();
```

... which when combined with another OrangeDot function creates something like this: 
[image: image of random dots over a canvas]

... but how do I create a series of dots that is concentrated around **one or several areas** of the screen? Something more like this?

[image: concentrated dot area]

Even just conceptual tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an exponential function to determine the distance with some random angle to achieve this.

```js
// dot count
const dots = 500;
// center point
const center = { x: 100, y: 100 };
// max distance from the center
const radius = 150;
// centripetal force, the larger it gets the more concentrated the dots are
const centripetal = 2.5;

const context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

var createBlueDots = function () {
 for (var i = 0; i <= dots; i++) {
  context.beginPath();
  const dist = (Math.random() ** centripetal) * radius;
  const angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  var rand_x = dist * Math.cos(angle) + center.x;
  var rand_y = dist * Math.sin(angle) + center.y;
  context.arc(rand_x, rand_y, 2, 1, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = "#0855A2";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
 }
}

createBlueDots();
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Is there any way to create this so the dots don't overlap?

Comment: It's rather tricky to dot that. You can put all the dots in an array, if the next dot is too close to any of the previous dots. Regenerate(not recommendid, slow) or simply skip this dot.